# Setting x ascis in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to write gnuplot plot with a file which has just one column. My file is missing X. My X is based on a row of numeber which go from 2.5 to 30 with a step of 0.1. Is there a command in gnuplot which does that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't to my knowledge do it directly in gnuplot, but you can make the correct file in the terminal just before running gnuplot (I am assuming your data file is called `file.dat`):

```
seq 2.5 0.1 30 > xaxis.dat
paste xaxis.dat file.dat > newfile.dat
```

Now you can plot `newfile.dat` in gnuplot.